# jQuery update css values

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

i have got a little problem with css on my homepage:
if i visit my page from a android device, and i scroll down,
the background image gets a little bit bigger, and if i
scroll up, it resizes again to the correct size.

I think the problem is: i load the pages with jquery's load()
into a div. Then the page size changes, but css still uses the
old size (at dynamic values (100% and cover).)

css:

```
body {
  background: #000000 url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If you don't know what i mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_ukAfoiqBo look at the background image

What i tried: i have no idea why this is happening (only on android devices) so till now i tried nothing :/

Xorg

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3301

Comment: @rafaeldefazio and still in Android 4.4.4 and Chrome? That issue was closed in 2012.

Comment: IDK if they already fixed this issue, however :\. Did you try the ways that the people posted on the above link?

Comment: @rafaeldefazio yes, still like described above :(